# Redux-Form old/incorrect field values when triggering field swap inside FieldArray

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using [Redux-Form 6.8.0](http://redux-form.com/6.8.0/) for my project. I am creating traveling application that calculates distance and duration of trip. Trip can have one or many stops. Stops can be picked from [Google Place AutoComplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)
and after picking desired place from google places application calculates distance with [Google Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) .

I managed to perform all calculations when user selects place from dropdown but when user swap stops/fields (used `fields.swap(indexA:Integer, indexB:Integer)`) incorrect results are displayed. Inside calculation method I "debugged" values and when user perform fields swapping, values (indexes) doesn't change at all but field array changes are rendered correctly.

Also, I am adding new elements in redux-form store because I need some values submitted even if they doesn't have fields at all. Not sure if that's good approach so I am open for suggestions.

Does someone knows where is the problem?

**Here is my code:**

Price calculation:

```
updateStopDistanceAndTime = () => {
    let self = this;


    if (this.props.fields.length >= 2) {

        let waypoints = [];


        this.props.fields.getAll().map(function (value, index) {

            console.log(value);

            if (value.place) {
                waypoints.push({
                    place: value.place,
                    placeId: value.placeId
                });
            }


        });

        calculateTimeAndValueBetweenStops(waypoints).then(function (result) {
            if (Object.keys(result).length > 0) {
                let currentValues;

                result.map(function (value, index) {
                    currentValues = self.props.fields.get(index);
                    if (value.end_address !== value.start_address) {

                        currentValues.distance = value.distance;
                        currentValues.duration = value.duration;

                        //  self.props.changeFieldValue('busRentForm', index + ".distance", value.distance);
                        //  self.props.changeFieldValue('busRentForm', index + ".duration", value.duration);
                    }
                    else {
                        //  self.props.changeFieldValue('busRentForm', index + ".distance", null);
                        //  self.props.changeFieldValue('busRentForm', index + ".duration", null);
                        currentValues.distance = null;
                        currentValues.duration = null;
                    }
                    self.props.fields.remove(index);
                    self.props.fields.insert(index, currentValues);


                });
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Field Array:

```
render() {
    const {
        stop,
        index,
        dayIndex,
        fields,
        isDragging,
        connectDragSource,
        connectDropTarget,
    } = this.props

    return connectDragSource(connectDropTarget(
        <div key={index} className="">
            <div>

            <div className="col-md-6 col-xs-7">
                <Field name={`${stop}.place`}
                       type="text"
                       component={renderStopInput}
                       icon={String.fromCharCode(97 + index)} // (97) is A in ascii table
                       label={(index === 0) ? "Starting location" : (index === fields.length - 1) ? "Destination location" : "Stop location"}
                       placeholder=""
                       index={index}

                />
                <span className={index !== fields.length - 1 ? "vertical-dash" : null}></span>


                {(index !== 0 && index !== fields.length - 1) ?

                    <button className="btn btn-fab btn-rearrange" type="button" onClick={() => {
                        fields.swap(index, index + 1);
                    }}><i className="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>

                    :

                    null}
            </div>




            <div className="col-md-1 stack">
                {(index !== fields.length - 1 && index !== 0) ?
                    <button className="btn-remove" type="button" onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}>
                        <span className="icon-Cancel"></span>
                    </button>
                    : null}
            </div>

            {(index !== fields.length - 1 && fields.get(index)) ?
                <StopInfo
                    departureTime={fields.get(index).time }
                    distance={fields.get(index).distance}
                    duration={fields.get(index).duration}
                />
                : null}



        </div>
        </div>
    ));
}
```